# How to connect a trained neural network built in MATLAB in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, matlab, neural-network

I have a trained neural network built in MATLAB and I want to use it in my C++ program. Is there any library of C++ which can read this neural network?

Comment: with a mex file

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the weights of your neural network and use it in your C++ program.

```
w1 = net.IW{1} %the input-to-hidden layer weights
w2 = net.LW{2} %the hidden-to-output layer weights
b1 = net.b{1} %the input-to-hidden layer bias
b2 = net.b{2} %the hidden-to-output layer bias
```

Comment: But how  can I use this information inside C++ program? I mean, I don't know how to apply these weights in a way to obtain the same results in the C++ program